# Share canvas across classes?

Tags: android, graphics, canvas, ondraw

I'm writing an app for android and I have a class setup that extends View. Inside that class I'm overwriting onDraw.

I have another class where I'm doing a lot of the processing. I was wondering if there was a way I can use the onDraw method inside the 2nd class too? The 2nd class isn't extending anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the 2nd class from the first, then pass the Canvas you receive as parameter to the method of the 2nd witch need it.

Something like.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  MyDrawer drawer = new MyDrawer(); //The 2nd class
  canvas.store(); //Use it to store the actual matrix and any further change you can do in the paint method will not take effect over the original matrix
  drawer.drawOn(canvas);
  canvas.restore();//Return the original matrix, any new paint will use the original matrix
  }
```

Comment: Example added, the drawOn(Canvas canvas) should be implemented to draw something on Canvas, and if possible create this object on the constructor and save it references to just draw on the onDraw method.